# Tensorflow not running on windows and pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I´m trying to make my first try with Tensorflow using windows 8.1 and Pycharm but I get an Tensorflow error.

I also installed everything in a virtual env with pip and runned the code in the command line with the same result.

**Some things I tried**

1. I read other posts relating the issue to the `msvcp140.dll` and I do have the C++ distributable installed.
2. Also found info related to downgrading to python 3.5. I actually use Python 3.7 and wouldn´t like to downgrade. I´m worried other apps won´t work. Can anyone confirm it won´t work with Python greater than 3.5?
3. Also read info about using Conda, but a the same time other info saying to avoid it, naming pip as the officialy supported method.
4. Also found info about my Intel® Pentium® Processor B980 not supporting AVX instructions. Is this a must when using CPU or only when using the GPU?

Any clues? Thanks in advance!

The following is the error message I get:

> Using TensorFlow backend. 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Lia
>   love/TestAi/Test1.py", line 4, in 
>       from keras.models import Sequential   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from . import utils   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from . import conv_utils   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       from .. import backend as K   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py",
>   line 89, in 
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\Users\Lia
>   love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\Lia love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

**Test code**

I estimate this is not a problem about my code, but I include it just in case.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

df = pd.read_csv("housepricedata.csv")

dataset = df.values

X = dataset[:, 0:10]
Y = dataset[:, 10]

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)

X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)

print("Keras model setup")
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your installation. Did you try running: `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"`?
You could try using 32-bit python if you're using 64-bit. Or [building Tensorflow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Pentium processors do not support [Advanced Vector Instructions ( AVX )](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions?wprov=sfla1) which are needed by TensorFlow if installed from [PyPI](https://pypi.org) through :

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Since, your CPU doesn't support AVX, you have two options to choose from:

1. **Use Anaconda**

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com) uses conda distribution index which is similar to PyPI. The TensorFlow conda build uses [MKL ( Intel Math Kernel Library )](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl). It works without AVX.

Download Anaconda as mentioned [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) and create a new conda enviroment as mentioned [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). Run this command:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

2. **Use builds from [tensorflow-windows-wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) repo.**

This repo contains a number of TensorFlow pip wheel files which are build using SSE instead of AVX. SSE build run without any compilation errors. Use this [file](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.13.1/py37/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) from the repo.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Python virtual environments are used to isolate package installation from the system (recommended)**

**Make sure these installation:**

```
python3 --version
pip3 --version
virtualenv --version
```

**Create a new virtual environment by choosing a Python interpreter and making a .\venv directory to hold it:**

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

**Activate the virtual environment:**

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

**Install packages within a virtual environment without affecting the host system setup. Start by upgrading pip:**

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip list  # show packages installed within the virtual environment

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

#Verify the install:
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

Open your project in pycharm and go to project setting and change the python run time to target this virtual env.
Hope this will help.